# multiple git accounts and ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I had a personal github account that was working fine with Visual Studio (Team Explorer). Now my employer gave me their account and all the time my Visual Studio refers to the old one. It gives me the following error:

An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

So i added another account in Windows Credential manager.

Now it still didnt work, then i saw this video: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

So i downloaded putty and generated a second ssh key (i dont know where the first one is!!)
and linked it to the new github account.
Now it asks me to add an identity to this public key. 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/sshkey2

which gives me 
"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

also when i try to list all public keys using
ls -al ~/.ssh

it gives me
ls: cannot access '/c/Users/spadmin/.ssh': No such file or directory

also my public key is saved as a .txt file not as a .pub file

What could i be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/48868#48868

i had to do

eval `ssh-agent -s`

ssh-add

and type full location c:/users/spadmin/.ssh/xyz.ppk